# How to remove an item with map function index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I used `map` function for an array in states. I have gave them an index and I want to when they are clicked, Remove from the array. I have written the code below but It will remove all indexes except the item was clicked :)
This is my code :

```
removeFromList(x) {
    this.setState({
        allTasks: this.state.allTasks.splice(x, 1)
    });
}
```

And :

```
this.state.allTasks.map((task, index) => {
    return <li key={ index } onClick={ () => this.removeFromList(index) }>{ task }</li>;
})
```

Comment: it's because splice returns deleted value

Comment: @guijob :\ So how should I remove that ?

Comment: @Herohtar I'm with you ...

Comment: just call: `removeFromList(x) { this.state.allTasks.splice(x, 1); }` and your allTasks will be the same except by removed element

Comment: You could use `.filter()`... something like `.filter((item, index) => index !== x)` should give you back an array of everything except for the one at the specified index.

Comment: @guijob It doesn't work because I need to rerender the ui so I called this.setState

Comment: @Herohtar I changed to this but not worked :
```
  removeFromList(x) {
    this.setState({
      allTasks: this.state.allTasks.filter(e => e !== x)
    });
  }
```

Comment: @Ali you are comparing elements instead of indexes in this approach, use second arg of filter

Comment: @AliBahaari The first parameter is the actual item, you need to include the second parameter to get the index. So `this.state.allTasks.filter((e, i) => i !== x) })`

Comment: @Herohtar Works like a charm ... Thanks for both of you ...